# Iteratively plot a data frame with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe (could be converted to array and vice versa for convenience for the task) which looks like

```
ID       FACTOR  VAL1    VAL2   VAL3     VAL4  
Apple    Fruits  0.0056 -0.0025 0.0039  -0.0037
Orange   Fruits  0.0067 -0.0039 0.0023  -0.0021
Carrot   Veggies 0.008  -0.0037 0.0095  -0.007 
Spinach  Veggies 0.0067 -0.0086 0.0024  -0.0042
Cucumber Veggies 0.0056 -0.0049 -0.0202 -0.0099
Grapes   Fruits  0.0055 -0.0044 0.0028  -0.0049
```

I want to be able to plot `VAL1` to `VAL4` in all combinations factored by the values of the column `FACTOR`, eg `VAL1~VAL2`, `VAL1~VAL3`, `VAL~VAL4`, `VAL2~VAL3`, `VAL2~VAL4`, `VAL3~VAL4`, all factored by fruits or veggies in `ggplot`.

This data is in a file data.txt.

My code:

```
val = read.table("data.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE)
df_val<-as.data.frame(val)

headers<-vector()
for (name in names(df_val)) {
    headers<-union(headers,c(name))
}

plots<- vector()
for (i in 3:5) {
    plots=union(plots,c(ggplot(df_val, aes(headers[i], headers[i+1])) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(FACTOR)))))
}

multiplot(plots,cols=3)
```

When I execute this, I don't get any results except few errors like

```
mapping: colour = factor(FACTOR) 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE 
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)
```

Is there an easy way to this?

Comment: Make `plots` a `list()`, not a `vector()`. You don't need `union()`, just `c()`.

Comment: I am trying to append all the graphs to the list. so union.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. `union` is a poor tool for it. You should have `plots = list()`, then `plots = c(plots, ggplot(...))`. Or even better `plots[[i]] = ggplot(...)`.

Comment: I would also guess that you should be using `aes_string()`, not `aes()` given what you're passing in.

Comment: Thanks that solved! But when I am trying to get all the combinations with two for loops, I get the same set of errors
`plots<- vector()`
`for (i in 3:5) {`
    `for ( j in 4:6) {`
    `plots=c(plots,ggplot(df_val, aes_string(headers[i], headers[j])) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(FACTOR))))`
`}`
`}`

Comment: Don't convert to `factor` inside `aes()`, do it in your data. Then, don't use `aes()`, use `aes_string()`, even for the `geom_point` layer.

Comment: Added aes_string. Still the error. But when I store the values in a pne dimensionall array, it works fine. but I cant use either i or j as it will not store all of the combinations. Eg plots[[i]]

Comment: Use `combn( c( VAL1',  'VAL2 ', 'VAL3 ',  'VAL4 '), 2)` to construct the 2-item combinations.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution, I shaped the data with `dplyr` and `tidyr` and then used facets in `ggplot2` to plot the combinations. This doesn't require combining multiple plots into one at the end.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Index of VALi
val_i <- 1:4 

# Shape the data as y ~ x
combos <- lapply(val_i[-max(val_i)], function(i) {
  df_val %>% 
    gather_("x_key", "x", paste0("VAL", (i + 1):max(val_i))) %>% 
    mutate(y_key = paste0("VAL", i),
           x_key = as.character(x_key)) %>% 
    unite(combo, y_key, x_key, sep = " ~ ") %>% 
    select_("ID", "FACTOR", "combo", y = paste0("VAL", i), "x") 
})
combos <- bind_rows(combos)

# Plot using facets
ggplot(combos, aes(x = x, y = y, color = FACTOR)) +
  facet_wrap(~combo, ncol = 3, scales = "free") +
  geom_point()
```

Note my points are in different places because I generated fake data.
[image]